# Use virtual property to access nested document in Mongoose model

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

Im trying to create a virtual item in one of my schemas, that will need access to data thats referenced by an item thats referenced in this schema (Yes, thats 2 references deep, connecting 3 schemas/models)

I've tried to simulate the code as close as I can here, using Model/Schema A/B/C..

This would be the schema for the **ModelA**, which contains the virtual item which depends on the references:

```js
// models/modela.js

// SchemaA for ModelA
const SchemaA = new Schema({
    _foo: {
        // References ModelB
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'ModelB'
    }
})

// Virtual `Modela.something`, which needs the data from ModelC.baz
SchemaA.virtual('something').get(function () {
    // How can I access ModelC.baz
    return 'Value from ModelC'
});
```

Then heres the schema for **ModelB**:

```js
// models/modelb.js

// SchemaB for ModelB
const SchemaB = new Schema({
    _bar: [{
        // References ModelC.baz
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'ModelC'
    }]
})
```

And the schema for **ModelC**:

```js
// models/modelc.js

// SchemaC for ModelC
const SchemaC = new Schema({
    baz: Schema.Types.String
})
```

As you can see above, what I need to do, is access **Modelc.haz** from within the virtual `something` item in **ModelA**

I thought that if I did both of the populations via the query itself, then maybe this would work, So I tried something like:

```js
this.find()
    .populate( '_foo' )
    .populate( '_foo._bar' )
```

Which didn't work (which I actually didn't really expect it to, but oh well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Model.populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.populate) method to achieve this:

```
ModelA
  .find()
  .populate({
    path: '_foo'
  })
  .exec(function(err, docs) {
    if (err) throw err;

    // Populate the '_bar' array of the '_foo' property which is
    // an instance of ModelB
    ModelB.populate(docs[0]._foo, { path: '_bar' }, function(err, result) {
      console.log('Showing ModelC.baz:', docs[0].something);
    });
  });
```

You can define the virtual property like this:

```
SchemaA.virtual('something').get(function () {
    // How can I access ModelC.baz
    return this._foo._bar[0].baz;
});
```

Comment: Thats awesome! Thank you. I notice that this will run the population on the independent document, meaning one at a time. Is there a way to have it populate all of them?

Comment: Nevermind the last comment, I see it works for all of them. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps, you can use pre hooks. Check my answer if you still need it.

Answer (score 0):

You can find more information about this at [this github issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2138). You can use query hooks.

I had similar issue, so I used it to populate reference models to use in a virtual function. Here is a sample.

```
const tutorialSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    videos: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Video'
        }
    ]
});

tutorialSchema.pre('findOne', function (next) {
    this.populate('videos');  // now can be accessed using this.videos
    next();
});

tutorialSchema.virtual('totalTime').get(function () {
    let times = [];
    times = this.videos.map((v) => {
        return v.duration;
    });
    if(times.length === 0) return 0;
    let totalTime; // find total time of videos and then return
    return totalTime;
});
```